# Exercise from Assem-Simson-Skowronski

Tags: homological-algebra

I'm having trouble with this exercise from Elements of the Representation Theory of Associative Algebras I: Techniques of Representation Theory.

The exercise in question is from chapter IV.

So, let $k$ be an algebraically closed field and let $A$ be a finite-dimensional $k$-algebra, and $M$ a left $A$-module containing no projective direct summands.

Say $F = \underline{Hom}_{A^{op}}(M, -) $ and $G = Tor_1^{A^{op}}(M, -)$. The exercise asks to prove that $F \cong G$.

Now I have been thinking about this exercise for a while, and I have no idea how to prove it.

One thing to note, the functor $F$ is the projective stabilization of the $Hom$ functor, and it takes a module $N$ and sends it to the module $Hom(M, N) / \mathcal{P}(M, N)$, where $\mathcal{P}(M, N)$ is the submodule consisting of all morphisms $f: M \rightarrow N$ that factor through a projective module.

For the life of me, I don't know how to prove this. I have tried to construct a surjective morphism from $Hom(M, N)$ to $Tor(M, N)$ having kernel $\mathcal{P}(M, N)$. This seems like sort of a lot of work to build up $Tor(M, N)$ from scratch and then figuring out where to send a morphism $f$.

Thanks!

Comment: Hint/Answer: It's the "dual version" of (the proof of) Auslander-Reiten duality (i.e. Theorem IV.2.13 in [ASS])

Comment: Thanks! I'll take a look at that. Also, someone on Math Overflow pointed out the exercise had a typo in it and that it should be between the functors $F = \underline{Hom}_{A^{op}}(Tr M, -) $ and $G = Tor_1^{A^{op}}(M, -)$. The exercise asks to prove that $F \cong G$. Here $Tr$ is the transpose.